# plt.imshow() not working in pycharm due to matplotlib not having a framework

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Image


Image(filename='test2.png')

# Returns numpy 2D array
cb_img = cv2.imread("test2.png")

# Print size of image:
print("Image size is: ", cb_img.shape)

# Print data type of image:
print("Data type of image is: ", cb_img.dtype)

#Display image
plt.imshow(cb_img)
```

When I try to run this on pycharm, no images are displayed and I also get an error for the plt.imshow function. I recon this might be because I was following a tutorial that used jupyter notebook so the framework in pycharm might be different.

Output:
Image size is:  (720, 1080, 3)
Data type of image is:  uint8
/Users/./PycharmProjects/pythonProject/earDetector.py:19: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Support for FigureCanvases without a required_interactive_framework attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later.
plt.imshow(cb_img)

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I don't think this warning message is necessarily connected to the fact that you can't see images. I can see the plots within PyCharm, but I still get this warning. I've only gotten that warning within PyCharm, not when I run on the terminal, so it must have to do with PyCharm's backend. You could try disabling the PyCharm backend in the preferences to see if you can at least open a window to view the plots outside of PyCharm.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, you do not get an **error** but a **warning**. More precisely, a `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning`.

Secondly, I hope you do not mind but I am presenting here a shorter example that (re)produces the same **warning**, which I will (re)use to elaborate on your question.

```
from PIL.Image import new as pil_img_new
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(pil_img_new(mode='RGB', size=(16, 16)))
```

Let us suppose that you use PyCharm to run this example and you will get the same `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning`. The **warning** message already helps you and the first thing that you should do is copy & paste the entire message into a search engine (e.g., Google). If you do that you will find a link to [a **matplotlib** webpage](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.6.0.html) that pinpoints **the API changes in version 3.6.0**, which you should definitely read. So, what you need to do is to specify a proper (available) **backend**.

Let us now slightly modify the given example to tell **matplotlib** to use a given **backend**.

```
from PIL.Image import new as pil_img_new
from matplotlib import use as mpl_use
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl_use('throw an error but give me the available backends!')

plt.imshow(pil_img_new(mode='RGB', size=(16, 16)))
```

If you run this example you will get the following **error**, though the list of values could be different.

```
ValueError: 'throw an error but give me the available backends!' is not a valid value for backend; supported values are ['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'GTK4Agg', 'GTK4Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'QtAgg', 'QtCairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']
```

The **error** is due to the statement `mpl_use('throw an error but give me the available backends!')` - obviously, the given value is **not** a valid **backend** -, but it really helps you! Using the information in the **error** message, you can now try each value to figure out which one works better for you. For instance, if the system in which you are running the example runs Mac OS X, it could be the case that `mpl_use('MacOSX')` suits your needs.

For completion purposes, here is a full example that works on Mac OS X Ventura and PyCharm 2022.1.2.

```
from PIL.Image import new as pil_img_new
from matplotlib import use as mpl_use
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl_use('MacOSX')

plt.imshow(pil_img_new(mode='RGB', size=(16, 16)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same issue. The only solution I found was to downgrade matplotlib to 3.5.3. Here's how to do this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#packages-tool-window

Comment: To make sure your information is valid even after your target link changed its content, please give an excerpt of your linked page

Comment: This is what I'm doing for a short-term solution, and adding the version change to our technical debt log.

Answer (score 1):

As [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213525/neil-traft) suggested, the fact that the image is not showing is unrelated with the warning.

You don't see your image because in Python scripts (which are different from Jupyter Notebooks) you have to add `plt.show()` at the end:

```
plt.imshow(cb_img)
plt.show()  # add this at the end of your script
```

The cause of the **warning**, instead, is PyCharm's SciView. Ideed, SciView does not support the interactive figures generated by Matplotlib (as stated in the [documentation of the Scientific Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html#console)).

To remove it without downgrading Matplotlib, it is sufficient to **disable the Scientific Mode**. In PyCharm, go to File | Settings | Tools | Python Scientific and remove the tick in "Show plots in tool window."

After this, the warning will disappear and you'll see the plot appearing on a different window.